# Firefox (only on windows xp) dosn't get values back from json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox, windows-xp

I use jquery .ajax() to send data and i get data back throe json! works fine on all browsers, except on "windows xp" Firefox.

.ajax() sends data with no errors! And I don't even get back any error messages from json!

I assume that error is in .ajax() because if there is no errors from json, then data is sent wrong.

```
function feedPage(div_id, feed_id, to, page){
    $.ajax({
        url: iloc,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "a=feed_page&div_id="+div_id+"&feed_id="+feed_id+"&page="+page+"&to="+to,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(d){
            var obj = eval('('+d+')');
            $("#page_now").html(obj.page);

            if(div_id == 1) {
                div_id = 0;
            }

            hideButton(obj.hide_button, div_id, feed_id, obj.page);
            delete obj["page"];
            delete obj["hide_button"];

            if(obj.rss_title) {
                $("#feed_title").html("<h1>"+obj.rss_title[0]+"</h1>");
                delete obj["rss_title"][0];
                $("#last_page").html(obj.last_page);
            }

            if(obj.all_feeds) {
                $("#jaunumi").append("ir");
                delete obj["all_feeds"];
            }

            $("#feed_id ul").scrollTop(0);
            $("#feed_id").empty();

            for (var i in obj){
                $("#feed_id").append(obj[i].title);
                $("#feed_id").append(obj[i].description);
            }

            if(div_id == 0) {
                var feed_div_offset = $("#feed_id").offset();
                var feed_div_offset_top = feed_div_offset.top - 100;
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: feed_div_offset_top }, 'slow');
            }

            $(".tablo_slash").html("/");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have u used firebug to see where the problem is?

Comment: yes! it shows NOTHING :D:D:D it sends data and receives back no errors, nothing!

Comment: from the server, try echoing something in the first line and check if you are able to see in Firebug

Comment: i wrote echo in first line at php and it didn't gave me back anything - so the problem is in ajax post, but i can't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem!

my "iloc" variable was rejected by browsers, because it contained "http://www......" so it assumed that file is on different domain and didn't even tried to look for it!